# Populate dropdown data in the customized Add function of Jqgrid from sql

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to customize the default add form in Jqgrid to add a dropdown and populate its dropdown data from a DB, not sure how to do so..

Following is my piece of code for the beforeShowForm which customizes the Name coloumn to provide a dropdown.

beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                                 $('#tr_Name').html('td class="CaptionTD">Name /td> td class="DataTD">  table> td> select role="select" id="resp" name="responsavel" size="1" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> option role="option" value="1">ABC /option> option role="option" value="2">XYZ  /option> option role="option" value="3">QWE /option> /select> /td>');

Here the option values are ABC,XYZ,QWE .. But i donot wish to hardcode it instead i want it to be populated from a SQL Database.

Requesting help.

Answer (score 0):

In the colModel you configure the `editoptions` with a dataurl and the `edittype:"select"`

```
colModel: [
{ name: "pers_genre_id", index: "pers_genre_id", width: 80, align: "right",
                editable:true, edittype:"select", 
                editoptions:{   
                        dataUrl:'ddl/ddl_genre.php',
                        }// end edit option
            },
]
```

The dataurl is the path of file who populate the content of your ddl :

```
<?php
    include("../dbconfig.php");

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM t_genre";

    echo '<select>';

    $result = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $result->execute();

    while($row = $result->fetch()) {

         echo '<option value="'.$row['gen_id'].'">'.$row['gen_genre'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';

?>
```